# Can i insert records into a second frame by clicking on a button in the first frame in java ?? (Swing)

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I have been on Java Swing for a while. I have been trying to insert records into a second frame upon the click of a button in the first frame. But have been unsuccessful so far. 
Here is the code that acts on thr button being clicked.I get **javaNullPointerException** error.

```
 private void submitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       

    try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kirty", "root", "11223344");
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from employee where id =?  ");
    String g = String.valueOf(ptf.getPassword());

    ps.setInt(1, Integer.valueOf(g));
     ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
     int count =0;
    while (rs.next())
    {

        if ( String.valueOf((ptf.getPassword())).equals (rs.getString(1))&&(utf.getText()).equals (rs.getString(2)))
                {
                   count =3;
                   break;
                }


    }
   if (count == 3)
   {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new frame3(),"Welcome to Database " + (utf.getText()));
                Database n = new Database();
                frame3 b = new frame3();

                 n.setVisible(true);
                this.setVisible(false);
                DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)n.tab1.getModel();
    while(rs.next())
        {
            model.addRow(new String[]{rs.getString(1),rs.getString(2),rs.getString(3)});
        }
                con.close();
            }

      else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new frame3(), "User doesn't exist!","Error Message", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

                   con.close(); }


    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new frame3(), e , "Error Message" ,JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);  
    }
```

Upon clicking the button, if correct info has been submitted, the second frame pops up with the table i have included in it, but the table remains empty. I have been trying a lot (didn't take help from the teacher though), but unable to catch the prob.I have not made any alterations to second frames code that is generated by NetBeans. As i said I get the javaNullPointer exception. Also, i would like to clarify one thing. tab1 is the table i have inserted in the second frame declared in the second class. Can i access tab1 using "." operator with the object of second class as i have already done.

The notations are as:

*emplpoyee - table in my database
*Database - my second class containing the second frame which includes the table

*Please understand i don't have complete command over Swing yet, I am just a starter stuck at the basic step.

Comment: You should be using a JDialog for user & password entry.  That way, you only have one JFrame for your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to do this is to have something in the second frame (possibly the frame itself) as a listener for activity on the button in the first frame, or better, some abstract entity that is nothing to do with the view at all. This way, the workflow is:

- the button changes some object that it has a reference to;
- that object fires its listeners;
- the second frame (which is a listener) reacts to the change.

Comment: I get it, not completely though. So, how do we make the second frame as the actionListener ?? Because i have inherited the second class to use the n.tab1(n is object of second class) table.Will you be please kind enough to show a small example of what u said ? I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just make the desired field as public and static mainly the class variable and upon your desired event e.g if you click a button update this variable with your desired value and then in the second frame you can call it as
      YourFirstFrame.YourClassVarinFirstFrame
//do something now